# Trying to do a join on a lookup list and its related list

Tags: list, list-view, lookup-column

I have a business requirement that I am trying to solve using lookup lists.

A business unit in my company deals with machine rentals and prints off a monthly report of all machines as well as the last update dealing with that machine for that month. If the machine wasnt used, the field is blank.

All of this is being done with a lot of manual steps and excel spreadsheets. I am trying to replace this using some lists in sharepoint but am a little lost how to proceed.

So far I have a list that is used as a lookup list that contains all of the information about the machines that can be used. I also have a list that contains updates, so you select the machine via the lookup field, fill in the extra information and save it.

Is there a way to like a sql join on the two lists? Have all machines from the lookup list displayed as well as the information from the most recent update written out?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is Connected Web parts, you just need to drop web parts of those two lists in a single page and than configure web part connections.

Please have a look at following articles:

[Connect data in Web Parts](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-data-in-Web-Parts-54a36fda-019c-49b3-ad33-0cd94bf70c1e)

[CONNECTING WEB PARTS WITH A SELECTOR AND A DETAIL PANE (SHAREPOINT 2010 VERSION)](https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/)